# Throw an error as a consequence of MySQL error OR as a consequence of checking the integrity of input fields?

Tags: sql, mysql, node.js, express

Imagine I have a table `article` as shown below :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    slug VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    content TEXT(8191) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

On my *ExpressJS* `createArticle` controller I receive user inputs from the `req.body` to perform create action. I can receive either all fields or just *title*.

```js
async function createArticle(req, res, next) {
  try {
    /* ? HANDLE UNDEFINED FIELD ERROR HERE ? */
    const { title, slug, content } = req.body;
    if (!title || !slug || !content) {
        throw new Error("Missing attributes");
    }

    /* ? HANDLE ERROR AS A CONSEQUENCE OF MySQL ERROR HERE ? */
    const [insert] = await pool.execute(
      "INSERT INTO article (title, slug, content) VALUES (?,?,?)",
      [title, slug, content]
    );

    // handle response
  } catch (err) {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

This example question relates only *create* action. But the same apply on *update*.

What error handling should I chose ?

Comment: *Imagine I have a table article as shown below* MySQL will fail - AI column must be a part of PK expression. *I can receive either all fields or just title.* Add DEFAULT clause to the columns whose values may be not provided. *But the same apply on update.* Enable General Log and look - maybe your app replaces UPDATE with DELETE+INSERT, for example?

Comment: @Akina, I've updated the question and added the PK. Updating the SQL table doesn't solve the problem at all (from where the error handling should happen ?), moreover there is no sense of having a default title, slug or content. Your answer regarding update has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should always validate the request payload in your Controller layer - there are many great tools to accomplish this, my favorite is [Zod](https://zod.dev/)
2. As for handling the SQL errors you should do that within your Service layer that will take care of the business rules such as violations to your SQL table constraints - wrap the save/update logic with try/catch block and gracefully handle the exceptions

Comment: I've been using zod after ur recommadation. Should I create two schema : one for create action and another for update action ? Because on creation, title slug and content must be required whereas on update user can update title or content or slug, etc. Should I use the `.partial()` method on the *Article* schema to have a *PartialArticleSchema type* for update ?

Comment: there is no need to duplicate the code as (like you have mentioned) Zod provides this functionality out of the box by using the `.partial()` method on the `z` object you have defined for your `create` schema